# Seg fault from multi-threaded cp program

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

I'm writing a program that is essentially a multi-threaded version of the "cp" command in UNIX. To do this, I created files for input/output, and initialized semaphores (required for assignment) to synchronize shared data. here is my code for main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //input/output file descriptors
    int fdIn, fdOut;

    //open files with proper rights
    fdIn = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    fdOut = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY| O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);

    //create and initialize semaphores
    semaphore_t *empty = nullptr,*full = nullptr;
    semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), empty, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 2);
    semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), full, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 0);

    //create and initialize structs to pass args to threads
    threadDataConsumer.fd = fdOut;
    threadDataConsumer.empty = empty;
    threadDataConsumer.full = full;
    threadDataProducer.fd = fdIn;
    threadDataProducer.empty = empty;
    threadDataProducer.full = full;
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;

    //create a thread for the producer and consumer
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, Producer, (void *)&threadDataProducer);
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, Consumer, (void *)&threadDataConsumer);

    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I believe this is where my problem lies as I haven't even begun to code the Producer and consumer threads. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where does the segfault occur?

Comment: Based on the above code, there are many places where it could occur. it could even be that not enough arguments were passed and you are attempting to access argv[2]

Comment: My suggestion, debug it. Try step in, step over. Eventually you will find it yourself.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `semaphore_t *` argument to `semaphore_create()` is for the return value.  That is, the function needs to know where to build the semaphore object.  You can't just pass in any variable of the correct type: read the documentation to see what it's for.  In your case:

```
semaphore_t sem_empty, sem_full;
semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), &sem_empty, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 2);
semaphore_create(mach_task_self(), &sem_full, SYNC_POLICY_FIFO, 0);
```

In general, learn how to use your debugger, which will tell you exactly in what line the segfault is occurring.

Also validate your input and check your return values.  There are other places where this could segfault.